# How to Get offline message count for muc room using Stophe js

Tags: ejabberd, strophe, strophe.js

I am developing a chat application using

> ejabberd and **Strophe.js** .
>   my question is how to get offline message of muc room.or give some example to how to implement message delivery receipts in strophe js plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of offline messages is applicable to conversations between a user and another user. I don't understand how it can be applied to MUC rooms, and most probably it cannot be done.

Comment: Is their any way to show unread message highlight using strophejs for muc